# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '!AA24!' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, type-conversion

I'm getting this error when I execute a stored procedure that contains negative values. Is there any way of converting or resetting a column value to fix it?

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '!AA24!' to data type int.

Code:

```
DECLARE @PartnerId VARCHAR(10) = 'ITS';
DECLARE @DASHBOARD_ID VARCHAR(20) = '-1'

DECLARE @AGENT_ID INT

SELECT @AGENT_ID = IdAgent 
FROM DGSDATA.dbo.AGENT WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE agent = @PartnerId

IF (@DASHBOARD_ID = '-1' OR @DASHBOARD_ID = '-2' OR @DASHBOARD_ID = '-3') 
    UPDATE [WAR_DB].[dbo].[WAR_DGS_CORE_USER] 
    SET PrimaryLayoutType = @DASHBOARD_ID 
    WHERE @AGENT_ID = USER_ID

UPDATE [dbo].[WAR_GLOBAL_DASHBOARD]  
SET IS_PRIMARY_DASHBOARD = 0 
WHERE @AGENT_ID = AGENT_ID AND IS_PRIMARY_DASHBOARD = 1
```

Comment: (1) Tag the question with the database you are using.  (2) You should be able to better isolate exactly where the error is happening.

Comment: is a sql server

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell where the exact conversion problem is occurring, but I suspect that `IdAgent` is really a string.  So I would start by changing:

```
DECLARE @AGENT_ID VARCHAR(255);  -- use the actual type of the agent

SELECT @AGENT_ID = IdAgent 
FROM DGSDATA.dbo.AGENT 
WHERE agent = @PartnerId;
```